# What's the advantage of using Logstash in ELK Stack?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

as far as i know Logstash is used to filter and convert data from incoming datas and send it to elastic search or anywhere else..
and also we can make data pipeline out of it like in logstash1 we validate datas after that in logstash2 we convert datas.. and so on.
I came to think can't a backend server do filtering and converting data?? as a batch server
it retrieves datas from log files, DB and filters and converts datas every sepecific time and send these datas to Elastic Search

of course there must be advantages of using logstash but i don't understand it clearly..
is it for performance reason??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to use logstash is to reduce coupling.
Imagine service which is logging to stdout. To integrate it with ELK stack, you might use logstash or modify service to push logs directly to the Elastisearch cluster.
The second option will cause tight coupling between service and Elasticsearch.
Another thing is that there are situations that you need to handle when integrating with Elasticsearch directly (eg. handling situation when cluster is unavailable).

Comment: I think if i make a batch server separately, do i still need to take care of coupling?? cuz i still think an independent batch server can work as logstash..

Comment: Logstash can scale if needed, deal with elasticsearch failures without losing data, provides easy ways to transform, convert and enrich your data. You can write your own service to receive and send data to elasticsearch, but you would need to deal with a lot of things that logstash already do, and do pretty well.

Comment: Yes, if you would implement batch server separately you would resolve the issue of coupling. Despite of that, it is rarely a good idea to implement your own solution when there is already a nice one available that serves the purpose. As @leandrojmp mentioned there are non-trivial issues to handle when implementing your own solution. However, it would made sense to implement something your own (which may be logstash plugin), if you have some requirements the logstash does not meet.